# Search for file name in full directory python

Tags: python

I have folder(let say master) that have sub folders and in turn they have sub folders.

```
example

Master
|
|_sub1
     |
     |_sub1_sub1
|
|_sub2
     |
     |_sub2_sub1
     |_filename
|
|_sub3
     |
     |_sub3_sub1
```

Now I want search for filename. I don't know in which folder it is. So I want to search only in master and if the file exist it should give me folder name in which it found the file. For the example it should give me the output _sub2

Is there any utility in python. I tried exists and isFile but didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfect for [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk):

```
import os

for root, _, files in os.walk('/path/to/master'):
    if 'filename' in files:
        print(os.path.split(root)[1])
        break
```

Comment: Yours is simpler, me like.

Comment: Crap I misunderstood what he meant.  Thanks I'll delete mine.